# Form field not displayed

Tags: php, symfony-forms, symfony

I have an entity class named Ad, it contains fields like

`id, banner, interstitial` 
The problem is when I try to create the form using this entity 'banner' text field is not displayed (not rendered), only the label.
I noticed that the id of the field is **ad_banner** if I change the id in browser inspect element, it will be displayed...
What is ad_banner in symfony, why it is hiding it?
I don't want to change the name of the field and I don't want to change the id from the twig because I want to keep it simple like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        {{ form_start(form) }}
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
        {{ form_end(form) }}
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried to change the id of the field from the form builder, but without success. Thank you! 
*Ad class*

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="banner", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $banner;
```

*AdType form*

```
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder->add('account', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => 'AppBundle:Account',
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'attr' => ['data-select' => 'true']
            ])
            ->add('banner', TextType::class, [
                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder' => 'Banner Id...'
                ]
            ])
            ->add('interstitial', TextType::class, [
                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder' => 'Interstitial Id...'
                ]
            ])
            ->add('submit', SubmitType::class, [
                'label' => 'Create',
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-sm'
                ]
            ])
    ;
}
```

*generated Html*

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label required" for="ad_banner">Banner</label>
    <input type="text" id="ad_banner" name="ad[banner]" required="required" placeholder="Banner Id..." class="form-control">
</div>
```

[image]

I took out the style because I was thinking maybe some js is hiding it.

Comment: It looks like you try to render in form fields which not exists in Entity. May be add option *'mapped' => false* for Form class properties?

Comment: it exists in entity...and is added to the DOM but with display none... wait I'm gonna update with an image

Comment: In this case this issue comes from **YieldManager** and do not relate to Symfony

Comment: what is this YieldManager? and how can I get rid of it?

Comment: Ad.yieldmanager.com

Comment: it is virus. You should remove it http://ru.wikihow.com/%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-Ad.yieldmanager.com. It is russian site - but workflow is clear

Comment: Are you kidding me? You know what AD BLOCK did this.... :-o  Will this happened to all users with ad block instaled?

Comment: According to your Chrome-screenshot yes, in this particular case it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is virus at your computer. Please remove it http://ru.wikihow.com/%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-Ad.yieldmanager.com and problems will gone

Comment: is ad block bro... thank for your suggestion. I will accept the answer because it point me to the problem :D

Comment: Thanks! Good luck :D